# How to implement authentication in flutter using riverpod

Tags: flutter, rest, authentication, riverpod

I am trying to do a login using riverpod, the login must call an api but at the moment I am using a fake api I want that while the api is called I can show a loader to the user and if everything is correct navigate to home.

I have the following:

**authentication_service.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/data/data_source/local/fake_data.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/data/models/models.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/models/models.dart';

class AuthenticationService {
  Future<Auth> login(User user) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
    User isName = fakeUsers.firstWhere(
      (element) => element.name == user.name,
      orElse: () => emptyUser(),
    );
    User isPassword = fakeUsers.firstWhere(
      (element) => element.password == user.password,
      orElse: () => emptyUser(),
    );
    if (isName.name != '' && isPassword.password != '') {
      return Auth(
          message: 'Succes welcome user',
          status: true,
          aditionalData: getRandomString(15));
    }
    return Auth(message: 'Credenciales incorrectas', status: false);
  }
}
```

**auth_provider.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/data/enums/enum_login_status.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/providers/app_providers.dart';

final userAuthProvider = StateProvider<Map<String, dynamic>>((_) => {
      'signedIn': false,
      'loaded': false,
      'status': LoginStatus.initialize,
    });

final saveUserTokenProvider = StateProvider.family<bool, String>((ref, token) {
  final localStore = ref.read(localStoreProvider);
  localStore.write(tokenKey, token);

  return true;
});

final userTokenProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) {
  final localStore = ref.read(localStoreProvider);

  return localStore.read(tokenKey);
});
```

**login_controller.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/data/enums/enum_login_status.dart';

import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/data/models/models.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/models/models.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/providers/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:watch_movie_app/src/domain/services/authentication_service.dart';

final authProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => AuthNotifier(ref));

class AuthNotifier extends StateNotifier<Auth> {
  final WidgetRef ref;
  dynamic _authRepository;

  AuthNotifier(this.ref) : super(Auth()) {
    _authRepository = ref.read(authRepository);
  }

  Future<void> login(User user) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> userAuthStatus = ref.read(userAuthProvider.state).state;
    userAuthStatus = {...userAuthStatus, 'loaded': true};
    final Auth loginResult = await _authRepository.login(user);
    state = loginResult;
    if (loginResult.status) {
      userAuthStatus = {'loaded': false, 'signedIn': true, 'status': LoginStatus.success};
    } else {
      userAuthStatus = {...userAuthStatus, 'loaded': false, 'status': LoginStatus.failed};
    }
  }

  void clearUser() {
    state = Auth();
  }
}
```

**auth.dart**

```
class Auth {
  final String message, aditionalData;
  bool status;

  Auth({this.message = '', this.status = false, this.aditionalData = ''});
}
```

versions packages:
flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.0

Flutter 2.10.2
Dart 2.15.1 DevTools 2.9.2

Comment: You could easily use AsyncValue in FutureProvider, read the docs [link](https://riverpod.dev/docs/providers/future_provider/)